# What window.location.href return in page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, window.location

I used window.location.href as element filter. However, when I click on the filter button, not all elements are displayed. The ones I manipulate are not displayed, but the ones I return directly from the DB are.

First, the button are like this, 1 for each month:

```
        <div class="monthsButton">   
          <button type="button" data-month="0" >2021</button>
          <button type="button" data-month="1" >Janeiro</button>
          <button type="button" data-month="2" >Fevereiro</button>
```

Second, to use the date as a filter, I use the following:

```
    const month = req.query.month;
    if(month > 0) {
      launch = lancamentos.filter(item => {    
        const data = new Date(item.data);
        return (data.getMonth() + 1) == month 
      })
    }
```

Finally, to do the action, the buttons are configured like this:

```
const monthsButton = document.querySelectorAll('.monthsButton button')
for (let button of monthsButton) {
  const month = button.dataset.month
  button.onclick = () => {
    window.location.href= `?month=${month}`
  }
}
```

The problem is that the filter button recognizes the date, uses it, but it doesn't show up when filtered, neither date and  numerics values.

Comment: You probably want to make `const month = req.query.month;` a number instead of a string. I still have no clue what your actual problem is. It hard to determine what your problem is from your question. What exactly is not working right?

Comment: A number is returned.

Comment: A number is returned which is in a format of a string. I also still have no clue what your problem is.

Comment: ok, i modified it to return a number, but the error continues

Comment: Can I ask why you get a date object, change it to a string, split it into parts, make a new date? Why are you not just using the getMonth from the first date object???? `data.getMonth()` should be no different than `LaunchUtils.formatDate(dataString).getMonth()`

Comment: Because I used another type of date and I haven't organized it yet. But I replaced it now, and the error continues.

Comment: `The problem is that the filter button recognizes the date, uses it, but it doesn't show up when filtered, neither date and numerics values.` Where does is use the data? where is this filter code used? I do not see that.....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235629/discussion-between-vinicius-pinto-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 0):

```
Run on you local, because use window.location ...
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="monthsButton">
    <button type="button" data-month="7" >Jul</button>
    <button type="button" data-month="8" >Aug</button>
</div>
<br>

<script>
    const monthsButton = document.querySelectorAll('.monthsButton button')
    for (let button of monthsButton) {
        const month = button.dataset.month
        button.onclick = () => {
            window.location.href= `?month=${month}`
        }
    }

    const lancamentos = [
        {
            name: 'Foo',
            date: 'Wed Aug 04 2021 18:18:14 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)' // Month 07
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar',
            date: 'Wed Jul 04 2021 18:18:14 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)' // Month 06
        },
        {
            name: 'Bar',
            date: 'Wed Aug 03 2021 18:18:14 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)' // Month 07
        }
    ]
    let launch = lancamentos
    const month = +window.location.search[7];
    console.log('Current month = ' , month)
    if(month > 0) {
        launch = lancamentos.filter(item => {
            const date = new Date(item.date)
            console.log('Item month + 1 = ', date.getMonth() + 1)
            return (date.getMonth() + 1) === month //  6 + 1  !== 8,  7 + 1 === 8
        })
    }

    window.document.write(JSON.stringify(launch))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's recommended to provide some explanation of the code helps other to understand the same